# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle and groups error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, acl

i am getting an error, when applying

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

i get a stack of errors, starting with

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Tracker\MembersBundle\Entity\User::addGroup() must be 

compatible with that of FOS\UserBundle\Model\GroupableInterface::addGroup() in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\mysite\src\Tracker\MembersBundle\Entity\User.php on line 14
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\mysite\app\console:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\mysite\app\console:22
PHP   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\mysite\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:118
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\mysite\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php:75
```

i figured out `User::addGroup()` and the `groups` implementation of `FOSUserBundle` ...but i do not know how to ultimately solve it...here are my two entities

[User](http://pastebin.com/vbgypx3K)
[Group](http://pastebin.com/wejKfGVU)

Update:
if i simply remove addGroup() from the User Entity, and go to the path
http://mysite.com/app_dev.php/group/new
i get a fatal error

```
 Fatal error: Declaration of FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\GroupFormType::getDefaultOptions() must be compatible with that of Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface::getDefaultOptions() in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\mysite\vendor\bundles\FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\GroupFormType.php on line 18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add FQCN of `GroupableInterface` in your `User` class e.g

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\GroupableInterface;
```

**Edit:**

You have to update symfony. As they have changed function signature of `getDefaultOptions`. Check [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/b7330456b698f7dd10bd2171c7075fc34c13858e).

Comment: thanks, but still does not help...when i go http://mysite.com/app_dev.php/group/new i get the error mention in the edit....or let me reframe...how can i add and define new groups with Roles...etc?

Comment: In `GroupFormType.php` what is the argument of the `getDefaultOptions`? `$options` or `array $options`. Second one is correct.

Comment: thanks, that did solve the problem....i am going to look on how i can create a pull request to fix that

Comment: Looks like this change have been made 2 days ago. check [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/commit/1e8f71c527adfbb93b0fdda578e8bb8d2052fe51). I think you have to update symfony.

Answer (score 1):

you should remove from:

> vendor\yourBundle\Entity\User;

getter setter group function coz it was already declared on

> use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User.php;

it can be duplicate function !

now generate your schema i hope it helps you :D