# How to use group

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin

I use FOSUserBundle and 'group' function

At first in my User.php
There were such getter and setter

```
/**
 * Add groups
 *
 * @param \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Group $groups
 * @return User
 */

public function addGroup(\Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Group $groups)
{
    $this->groups[] = $groups;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove groups
 *
 * @param \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Group $groups
 */
public function removeGroup(\Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Group $groups)
{
    $this->groups->removeElement($groups);
}

/**
 * Get groups
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getGroups()
{
    return $this->groups;
}
```

but,this error happens

```
FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Declaration of Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User::addGroup() must be compatible with that of FOS\UserBundle\Model\GroupableInterface::addGroup()
```

in FOS\UserBundle\Model\GroupableInterface

```
public function addGroup(GroupInterface $group);
```

in my Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User

```
public function addGroup(\Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Group $groups)
{
    $this->groups[] = $groups;

    return $this;
}
```

How can I adjust the argument type or correct this error?

For now,I have commented out these three function.

at that time it looked works well.

But now ,I use Sonataadmin bundle and in

@SonataAdminBundle/Admin/UserAdmin.php

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper){
    $formMapper
      ->with('General')
      ->add('groups','entity',array('property' => 'name',
              'multiple' => true,
              'class' => 'UserBundle:Group',
      ))
}
```

it shows this form correctly but when I push submit button to regist,

it shows

```
Error: Call to a member function contains() on a non-object in ~~~/FOS/UserBundle/Model/User.php line 572
```

in /FOS/UserBundle/Model/user.php
there is function likt this

```
public function addGroup(GroupInterface $group)
{  
   var_dump($group);# I added to check
   if (!$this->getGroups()->contains($group)) {
        $this->getGroups()->add($group);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

var_dump($group) shows

```
object(Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Group)#923 (3) { ["id":protected]=> int(2) ["name":protected]=> string(12) "TeacherGroup" ["roles":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

I guess it has group information correctly..

How can I fix this problem?

my whole user.php

// src/Acme/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;


use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\GroupableInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * 
 */
protected $id;
/**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Lesson", mappedBy="teacher")
 */
private $LessonAsTeacher;
/**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Lesson", mappedBy="student*removethis : name of the variable in Lesson.php*")
 */
private $LessonAsStudent; 

  /**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Sex", inversedBy="sex*removethis : name of the variable in user.php*")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sex", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
 */
private $sex;


 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Group")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fos_user_user_group",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $groups; 
    /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your first name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
 * @Assert\MinLength(limit="0", message="The name is too short.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
 * @Assert\MaxLength(limit="255", message="The name is too long.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
 */
protected $firstname;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your last name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
 * @Assert\MinLength(limit="0", message="The name is too short.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
 * @Assert\MaxLength(limit="255", message="The name is too long.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
 */
protected $lastname;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */  
protected $birthday;

    /**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="createdAt", type="datetime")
 */
private $createdAt;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="updatedAt", type="datetime")
 */
private $updatedAt;



public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // your own logic
}
public function getFirstname()
{
    return $this->firstname;
}
public function setFirstname($name)
{
    $this->firstname = $name;
    return $this;
}
public function getLastname()
{
    return $this->lastname;
}
public function setLastname($name)
{
    $this->lastname = $name;
    return $this;
}
public function getSex()
{
    return $this->sex;
}
public function setSex($sex)
{
    $this->sex = $sex;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}





/**
 * Set age
 *
 * @param integer $age
 * @return User
 */
public function setAge($age)
{
    $this->age = $age;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get age
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getAge()
{
    return $this->age;
}

/**
 * Set birthday
 *
 * @param \DateTime $birthday
 * @return User
 */
public function setBirthday($birthday)
{
    $this->birthday = $birthday;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get birthday
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getBirthday()
{
    return $this->birthday;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */

public function prePersist()
{
    $this->createdAt = new \DateTime;
    $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function preUpdate()
{
    $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime;
}

/**
 * Set createdAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $createdAt
 * @return User
 */
public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
{
    $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get createdAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getCreatedAt()
{
    return $this->createdAt;
}

/**
 * Set updatedAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
 * @return User
 */
public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
{
    $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get updatedAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getUpdatedAt()
{
    return $this->updatedAt;
}


/**
 * Get groups
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getGroups()
{
    return $this->groups;
}


/**
 * Add groups
 *
 * @param \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Group $groups
 * @return User
 */
//  public function addGroup(\Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Group $groups)
//  {
//      $this->groups[] = $groups;

//     return $this;
// }

/**
 * Remove groups
 *
 * @param \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Group $groups
 */
//  public function removeGroup(\Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Group $groups)
//  {
//      $this->groups->removeElement($groups);
//  }
}
```

my whole Group.php

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\Group as BaseGroup;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_group")
 */
class Group extends BaseGroup
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
   protected $id;

 /**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
  public function getId()
  {
    return $this->id;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10139318/1443490

Comment: THanks cheesemacfly ,I checked this thred and try to solve,but it doesn't...it seems they are talking about bit older version,but good reference.I edited and added additional information on this topic

Comment: I have edited main article.

Comment: We do agree that when you write `Group.php` in your question you mean `User.php`, right? Can you show us the code of those 2 entities?

Comment: Hi cheesemacfly ,yes you are right i miswrote name . now I added 2 entities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you override `getGroups()` like this:

```
/**
 * Get groups
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getGroups()
{
    return $this->groups;
}
```

But you never initialized `$this->groups`, so when you call `$this->getGroups()->contains()`, it says that `$this->getGroups()` is a `non-object`, which is true!

To solve this you have 2 solutions.

You can initialize `groups` in the constructor of `User`:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    &this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Or you can change the `getGroups()` function to return a new object if `groups` hasn't been initialized:

```
public function getGroups()
{
    return $this->groups ?: $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

In both cases, don't forget to add `use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;` at the beginning of `User.php`.

Comment: thanks!!! I use second solution, it works!!!!I appreciate your great help!Notes:I added __toString() function in group.php to list the data.     
 public function __toString(){
     return $this->name;
 }

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error:

```
FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Declaration of Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User::addGroup() must be compatible with that of FOS\UserBundle\Model\GroupableInterface::addGroup()
```

After searching I found out ([FOS Git Issue 988](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/988)) that this special error is a Doctrine 'Bug' or sth.

Doctrine should not generate the method at all because there is an implementation of addGroup() in the base class.
I worked around it by modifying the signature from

```
public function addGroup(\MyBundleNamespace\Entity\Group $groups)
public function removeGroup(\MyBundleNamespace\Entity\Group $groups)
```

to

```
public function addGroup(\FOS\UserBundle\Model\GroupInterface $groups)
public function removeGroup(\FOS\UserBundle\Model\GroupInterface $groups)
```

This way you prevent Doctrine from generating these two functions with the wrong signature.

Version Infos:

```
Symfony       2.2.1
DoctrineORM   2.2.3
FOSUserBundle 1.3.1
PHP           5.4.4-14
```

Maybe this can help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem and the simple solution was to change the declaration of the groups variable from public to protected:

```
 /**
  * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
  */
 protected $groups;
```

Answer (score 0):

solution is simply: remove all setters and getters from your own entity in your own userBundle and always run doctrine:generate:entities for specyfic bundle, not for all.